# console log not goes to tomcat.log(catalina start -security > tomcat.log)

Tags: java, file, logging, tomcat7, securitymanager

Im using security manager in my tomcat.
I need all the consol logs to be written in the tomcat.log file.
Fo this im using this cmd

```
catalina start -security > tomcat.log
```

But the log not goes to tomcat.log rather it is again writing in console only.

How can i write this log into a separate file?

Answer (score 1):

Check out your catalina.out file. By default logs are redirected to $CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out file. To override default configuration ,you can set Tomcat environment variables **CATALINA_OUT** in setenv.sh which is full path to the file where stdout and stderr will be redirected.